# International Boundaries and the Age of Majority

Tags: humans, dragons, diplomacy

My world has at four major powers active on it:

The Loong Empire, a nation-state of eastern style dragons

New Draconia, a nation-state of mainly western style dragons

Mount Celestia, the home of the draconic gods and the afterlife

Minecraftia, a nation composed of various species, but primarily humans

All of these nations are part of the Proxima Alliance, originally founded by the natives of Minecraftia during a time when the Loong Empire was in hiding, New Draconia had not yet been formed, and Mount Celestia was not accessible to mortals. Now, aside Minecraftia, the other three nations are primarily inhabited by dragons.

Dragons live an average of 20,000 years, so their traditional age of majority was 1,500. The Loong Empire and Mount Celestia still follow this, and though New Draconia is slightly more flexible, they mostly do as well. There are dragons both eastern and western that live in Minecraftia, where the age of majority used is the human one, 18.

What would make the most sense if a dragon traveler went on a trip from Minecraftia to one of the other nations? Would they be treated as a child, or would they be considered adults by dint of where they came from? Would a hospital on Mount Celestia consider an 80 year old Minecraftian dragon to be a minor if they came in for emergency treatment after an accident? What if a traveler lost their passport? Would their nation's embassy be the only way to be treated as an adult?

Point is, I'm confused. If someone is an adult in their home country, does that carry to another, even if the age of majority over there is different?

EDIT: Minecraftia uses the same rules for humans and dragons for the most part due to the fact that I'm using D&D style dragons-they're genius-level smart from birth.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *"If someone is an adult in their home country, does that carry to another, even if the age of majority over there is different?"* It depends for what purpose -- there is no such thing as one master cutoff-age which applies to all purposes. But for most usual purposes, such as buying alcoholic beverages, consent to sexual relations, or the ability to stand in justice, the local rules apply. At least here on Earth. (And why does Minecraftia have the same rules for humans and dragons? It makes no sense. An 18 years old dragon is a babbling toddler.)

Comment: @AlexP, so a Minecraftian dragon couldn't drink in any of the other three nations. What about informed consent/refusal of medical care? Would they have say in a medical setting?

Comment: I am not familiar with the specific example. But generally, most age-related regulations speak about "persons", or "partners", or "patients" and so on, and *not* of "citizens". I don't think I have ever heard of an age-related regulation which said that specifically *Romanian* citizens had to be over 14 or whatever -- it said "bicyclists" had to be over 14 to ride on public roads.

Comment: But again, most likely *all* four countries would have different age-related rules for humans and dragons. They develop at vastly different paces, and having the same rules for both would be silly.

Comment: It's like this. A young adult dragon goes from young-dragon-ville to old-dragon-ville and is treated as their age according to local rules, i.e, as a child. They complain about this to the young-dragon-villian embassy, who complains to the old-dragon-villian government, which decides whether or not it cares enough to update the law.

Comment: There's a nation on Earth where the age of sexual consent is 20. Another where the age is 11. Does this mean that if a family with an 11-year-old from A travels to B an adult in B can legally engage that 11-year-old? ***It's not that simple, which is the problem with your question.*** Most nations have or respect laws governing how people from *other countries* are treated within their own. Local laws must be respected, but the laws of other countries aren't ignored. In short: there will be a massive body of law governing how people from one nation can relate to each other when inside another.

Comment: And in that regard, the question is story-based, because there is no right answer other than the one you, the author, wants. It's just a matter of creating just enough of that massive body of law to rationalize the choice you want.

Comment: @JBH, Thank you. I'll definitely be thinking on this.

Comment: Does an 18-year-old dragon have similar judgement and ability to an 18-year-old human, or is it intellectually a toddler?

Comment: It's not clear if you are asking about differences in law (modern? ancient?) or differences in culture. There are so many variations that you can have it come out just about any way you want. Thousand-year-old dragons need a note from their mother? Sure, why not. Just do note that Minecraftia will seem an attractive haven for rebellious runaway dragons under the age of 1500, so their dragon population seems likely to increase rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simplest solution would be to split dragon youth into three stages.

- human young : from birth to 18 years old
- human age : from 18 through 100 years old
- dragon young : from 100 through 1500 years old.
  and then add to that
- dragon adult : 1500 years old and older

Rights and privileges could then be granted to both humans and dragons on an equal time scale.  Human-Young citizens of either human or dragon lineage would have almost no rights at all.  Human-Age citizens of either race would be granted those rights appropriate for a person of that young age.  And so on...

Then to spice it up, you could grant special citizens (heroes, scholars and royalty) higher status based on their proven maturity.  This provides a wonderful reward to be won by your dragon and human characters as they succeed in their adventures.

The beauty of this system is that it allows people to be treated consistently across all the lands and provides a simple solution to challenges of being a wandering young dragon.

Answer (score 3):

**Most likely not**

(This is almost certainly a story-based question, so in an effort to answer it, I'm going to assume that you're asking for a transferal of the system used on Earth and intend to use a similar one. If you're looking to build one from scratch, this question is too opinion-based and story focused and can't be answered.)

Under conventional international law, age of majority is wherever you currently reside. For instance, an 18 year old is not permitted to purchase alcohol in the USA. However, if a US resident flies internationally and makes a stopover in, say, Amsterdam, where the legal drinking age is 18, someone who is 19 can legally purchase a beer in Amsterdam with no repercussions. That is, countries which have treaties with each other respect the other countries' ability to execute the law within their jurisdiction. In American, this concept is called 'Full Faith and Credit' though granted that's the version of it which applies only in regards to states respecting other states laws, its just the best term I could find for such a concept.